# MobileServiceClient Where() syntax

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am writing a mobile application in Xamarin with an Azure mobile back-end. I am using `MobileServiceClient` to connect to my SQL database in Azure. I have a table in the cloud which I made using Azure's `EasyTables`.

I am trying to fetch data from this table using `ToListAsync()` which I would like to attach a `.Where()` clause to, such that I only fetch data where the `user` field in my table is "MyCoolUser".

What should my `.Where()` method look like?

Comment: `.Where(i => i.user == "MyCoolUser")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should my .Where() method look like?

As Easy Table supports [OData](http://www.odata.org/), we could do it with following code:

```
  var user =  MobileServiceClient.GetTable<T>().Where(x => x.user=="MyCoolUser").ToListAsync().Result
```

We could catch the request with fiddler, then could see that filter is 
included in the request[image]